# print star for multiple reviews

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use this code to print rating of product but i want to print list of reviews on same page for that i need .each() method can anyone tell how can i implement.

```
  function generateRatingStars() {
    var rating = $('.fixture').text();
    var percent = Math.round(rating * 2) * 10;
    console.log(rating);
    function addScore(rating, $domElement) {
        $("<span class='stars-container'>")
                .addClass("stars-" + rating)
                .text("★★★★★")
                .appendTo($domElement);

    }
    ;
```

css code is:
        addScore(percent, $(".fixture"));

```
   }


         .stars-container {
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
         color: transparent;
         }

        .stars-container:before {
         position: absolute;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         content: '★★★★★';
         color: lightgray;
        }

       .stars-container:after {
        position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
        content: '★★★★★';
        color: gold;
        overflow: hidden;
          }
```

Html code is:

Comment: Welcome! Take out your inner function out first. Call this function in a simple `for` loop.

Comment: Please add your html as well.

Comment: "for that i need .each() method can anyone tell how can i implement." ...did you read the documentation examples first? What did you try? This is not a free tutorial site, but we'll help you with your attempt at coding.

Comment: Question needs more details, it is in complete

Answer (score 0):

function generateRatingStars() {

```
    $.fn.stars = function () {
        return $(this).each(function () {

            var rating = parseFloat($(this).html());

            var percent = Math.round(rating * 2) * 10;

            var span = $("<span class='stars-container'>")
                    .addClass("stars-" + percent)
                    .text("★★★★★");
            $(this).html(span);

        });
    };
    $('span.stars').stars();
}
```